# How to get rid of some capital letter's horizontal offset/padding

Tags: html, css, fonts, alignment, typography

The following example pretty much sums it up.
This code:

```
<h1 style="background-color:#F2D680">
  K
</h1>
<h1 style="background-color:#BAC9A9">
  T
</h1>
```

Produces:

[image: misaligned letter]

As you can see, the letter `K` is displaced (its leftmost edge does not align with `T`'s leftmost edge)
Are there any CSS tricks to conquer such misalignment?

Comment: I would assume that is down to the font you are using

Comment: Looks like more of an issue with the font you're using than anything else. You could always offset by `margin-left`, but this would require always knowing the first letter beforehand.

Comment: You could try removing an extraneous padding but if that's what the glyph 'block' is..then perhaps `letter-spacing` is what you are after

Comment: It seems to depend on the font. Using Times New Roman displaces the T instead of the K. Maybe a monospace font like Courier doesn't produce this?

Comment: Unfortunately any other font would be inconsistent with my company's CI

Comment: what font are you using?

Comment: Then I gues you will have to set an offset with padding, or using text-indent for every letter you need, like Bojan Petkovski already assumed.

Comment: Why do you even care? Are your letters really that big that you notice?

Comment: The font size I'm using in header causes up to 4px displacement. This is unacceptable for my client

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the design of the glyphs. Many glyphs have some empty space on the left or on the right of the visible symbol. This spacing is outside the scope of CSS. You cannot use CSS to left-align the visible symbols in the glyphs, because CSS cannot “get inside a glyph”.

However, you can adjust spacing with CSS in different ways, possibly undoing the effects of the space in the glyphs. This would need to be done on the basis of inspecting the glyphs in the font being used, and naturally when your font suggestion is not honored for some reason (e.g. the user’s system has not got the font), strange effects may be caused.

So this would be unreliable tuning, but sometimes it might suffice. Example:

```css
h1 { font: 96pt Arial }
```

```html
<h1 style="background-color:#F2D680; text-indent: -0.04em">
  K
</h1>
<h1 style="background-color:#BAC9A9">
  T
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the cause is the font.
To my mind, the only solution is to change of font (one without this problem)...

(Or to use CSS to playing with margins in each case)

Comment: Does that particular font feature have a name, so I can search for a font that doesn't have it?

Comment: Monospace Fonts shouldn't have this issue, I guess

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by the [kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) of the font. It vary from font to font how much the kerning (space between each character) will be.
You can try to use text-indent to make it align as you like. It also allows using  negative values

Example

```
text-indent: -5px;
```

Comment: It wouldn't eliminate the difference between various letters, just move the text a fixed amount of pixels to the left.

Comment: This is not kerning (which means adjusting spacing between adjacent letters and is normally not applied by most browsers) but glyph design.

Answer (score 0):

It's the nature of fonts. Every glyph has white in front and behind each shape. Otherwise all shapes would stick together. It is important to realise that the white is as important to the shape of the glyph as the actual shape itself. There are even glyphs with negative offset and a lot of time and devotion goes into designing these offsets.

The reason that not all white is equal is to optically compensate. Yes, you read it well. The font designer added white to make the glyphs look evenly spaced. To compensate the black from the stem of the K to the left gap under the T.

So putting two glyphs on top of each other in a large size is an exceptional use case. Normally things work out okay, but if it bothers you, or your client, just correct the position to your (clients) liking and be done with it.

Answer: `margin-left: -4px;`

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the font using FontCreator. I think, this is the easiest way. ;)
Also, you can change style of capital letter using :first-letter.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

```
h1{
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Zoom in. The difference is still there

Comment: Of course it works with Times, but with Arial, as provided in the question, this solution doesn't work. Why? Because the offset is caused by the font itself.